# Ubuntu One for Android without Google play

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

Is there a way to get the Ubuntu One apk file? My Android device is not supported by Google.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **F-droid**. An Open Source alternative for Google Play:

[F-DROID](https://f-droid.org/)

On App just search for Ubuntu or Ubuntu One. But unfortunately i could not find Ubuntu One Music on it.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean the Ubuntu One Files for Android app download it from

https://launchpad.net/ubuntuone-android-files/trunk/1.2.7/+download/u1f-1.2.7-google.apk

If you want all the releases download it at

https://launchpad.net/ubuntuone-android-files/+download

Answer (score -1):

Try this link: 
[Ubuntu One Android App from Google Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubuntuone.android.files&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS51YnVudHVvbmUuYW5kcm9pZC5maWxlcyJd)

Sign in and install: use the same Eami ID in your phone(as the primary email account) and on the web.